# Microsoft Point of Service for .NET wont let me delete devices

Tags: point-of-sale, opos, pos-for-.net

I'm trying to delete a device (an old cashdrawer) from a POS-computer running windows 10, but so far, no luck.

What I've tried to do is; open cmd, head to the install-location of ms pos, and run this command:
`posdm deletedevice /soname:drawer1`
But this gives me this error-code:
`POSDM: Exec 'DeleteDevice' failed: res=80131500: No ErrorInfo available.`
I have no idea how to fix this, and no idea why it gives me an errorcode. I can without a problem add new devices, but not delete them.

Does anyone have any experience with Microsoft point of service for .net?

Answer (score 1):

After looking for along time I ended up with a program from Epson called "Epson OPOS ADK" (Version 3.00E Upos 1.14). That program let me remove the cashdrawer without any problem.
Still don't know why I got the error, but atleast this fixed my problem.